# Adding and removing trend to time series data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data-science, reverse-engineering, trend

I have time series data. By linear regression I have removed the increasing trend from the data.
Is it possible to add the same trend to data the data predicted by linear regression?

The trend has been removed. Now I want to get the original data from the detrended data. As shown in the chart below.
[image: figure]

To make the scenario clear, suppose I have original_data.csv remove the increasing trend from the original data by using linear regression and save the detrended data in detrended.csv now my aim is to get back the original_data from the detrended data. Hope that it would be clear now.

Comment: Your question needs more clarification. If you needed the original data then you would just add the trend back to the detrended series, but obviously that is not what you need.. please explain what it is that you will get as final series and how would that be different from your Original Data series.

Comment: Suppose I have original_data.csv remove the increasing trend from the original data by using linear regression and save the data detrended data in detrended.csv now my aim is to get back the original_data from the detrended data. Hope that it would be clear now.

Comment: If you do not memorize the trend data or parameters of your linear regression, it is impossible to know the trend you removed. However, I suppose you can memorize the parameters of the linear regression (simply the equation of the line), then it should be straight forward. Is there something else you are intending to do?

Comment: Bro, I am not getting you. What do you want to say?

Comment: Use your original linear regression to add back the trend. Or you can simply use the parameters (e.g. in form aX+b) to add back the trend. I am not aware how much you know about how linear regression works, if you are a beginner I suggest you do bit of study also.

Comment: Thank you, got it. Yeah I am new to statistical approaches.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251201/discussion-between-hasanat-and-jdsurya).